# Airflow - Error when configuring User authentication

Tags: airflow

I am trying to setup login page for Airflow. I am getting an error when I try to update the password using (user.password = 'set_the_password')

Getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/hybrid.py", line 873, in __set__
    raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Could anyone help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in `python` interpreter:

```py
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'USERNAME'
user.email = 'EMAIL'
user._set_password = 'PASSWORD'.encode('utf8')
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
```